# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while removing items from collection

Tags: java, collections

I am learning Java's Collection framework. I wrote this little program to check why we can't use For-each to remove elements.

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class intro{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Rajat");
        names.add("Saxena");

        for(String name:names){
            names.remove(name);
        }

        for(String name:names){
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Saxena
```

And

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class intro{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("Rajat");
        names.add("Saxena");
        names.add("Arvind");

        for(String name:names){
            names.remove(name);
        }

        for(String name:names){
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at intro.main(intro.java:15)
```

How come just the addition of one more element to collection is causing the error?

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you remove an element from a collection while looping over the collection, you'll get a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). This is partially why the [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface has a `remove()` method. Using an iterator is the only safe way to modify a collection of elements while traversing them.
The code would go something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("Rajat");
    names.add("Saxena");
    names.add("Arvind");
for (Iterator<String> iterator = name.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
           String string = iterator.next();
           if (string.isEmpty()) {
                 iterator.remove();
}
}
```